# Friends can't join my group but I can join their group

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

So have been playing with friends and everyone I go to invite them to my group party they can never join mine but I can join their party. And when I am in the party they can not make me the party leader and every time I try to do a quest with them they don't don't get my invite?

Has anyone else had this problem and know how to fix it?